# Assigning a list to another list in a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, reference

If you have the following list of lists:

```
>> A = [[1], [2]]
```

And then say you assign the 2nd list to the first list by:

```
>> A[0] = A[1]
```

You end up with the following:

```
>> print A
[[2], [2]]
```

So A[0] and A[1] point to the same list now. If you append an element to the first by:

```
>> A[0].append(3)
```

You will get the following:

```
>> print A
[[2,3], [2,3]]
```

However, if you try to delete the first list by:

```
>> del A[0]
```

Then only one list is removed, as follows:

```
>> print A
[[1,2]]
```

**Q1.1: Why is the behavior different?** One might expect both lists to be removed.

Clearly, if one just wants to make a copy of A[1] then the following works correctly:

```
>> A = [[1], [2]]
>> A[0] = list(A[1])
>> print A
[[2], [2]]
>> A[0].append(3)
>> print A
[[2,3], [2]]
```

The problem with this is that its running time is linear with the size of the list to copy, i.e., A[1].

**Q1.2: Can one copy a list from another without linear-time copy operation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1.1**.

You have to differentiate between an object and object identity. Identity is just a logical address to the memory cell of the object. When you are doing `A[0] = A[1]`, you don't actually copy the object, but you get a new identity to the object. After `A[0] = A[1]`, you have two **identities** `A[0]` and `A[1]`  to the same object, so when you do `A[0].append(...)` or `A[1].append(.)`, what is actually being affected is the same object.

Now about lists. Lists in Python don't hold objects. They hold identities of the objects. You can check this by comparing

`sys.getsizeof([1])` and `sys.getsizeof([1000000000000000000000000000000])`,

both will have the same size although `10000000000000000000000000000000` is obviously heavier than `1`.

What `del` does is, it removes an element from the list, which happens to be one of the two **identities** and not the object, so when you have a list that holds two identities to the same object and `del` one of them, you still keep the object and the other identity *because the object is still referenced*.

**Q1.2**.

If you want to copy, you can just do `A[0] = A[1][:]`, which will assign `A[0]` to a slice. It should be faster. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612990/1527217).

Comment: I would say "references" instead of "identities"; I think "references" is the more commonly used terminology?

Comment: @Vultaire It might be but "identity" is used in python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html), so I just used "identity" to keep it consistent.

Comment: And from @itzmeontv's answer, you can get the identity value by `id(A[0])`.

Comment: @TrainedScarab I might have been wrong about O(1) but it should be faster. I updated the answer.

Comment: @khajvah Interesting; I didn't see how the docs used the term.  Thanks; I'll keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

del A[0] 
doesn't means to delete an entry of A[0] element And would be deleted at garbage collection. It just stand for deleting a reference link from A[0] variable to list ([2,3]).

Answer (score 0):

**Q1.1: Why is the behavior different? One might expect both lists to be removed.**

```
del A[0]
```

is not deallocating the memory of `list` `[2,3]` or nor deleting the `list`.It just removing tag or referevce `A[0]` to the list `[2,3]`.

**Q1.2: Can one copy a list from another without linear-time copy operation?**

```
A[0] = A[1][:]
```

For example

```
A = [[1], [2]]
A[0] = A[1][:]

>>id(A[0]),id(A[1])
(140215217604552, 140215217619208)
```